# May I know how to create / generate XML using elementtree

Tags: python-3.x, xml, lxml, elementtree

```
...
para1= ET.SubElement(root,'para')
anchortag=ET.SubElement(para1,'anchor')

anchortag.set()
para1.text= " sometexthere"
```

I tried with the above code snippet,but couldn't get the expected output.I don't want to create a new para tag that would take the text to newline.
result of above code :
`<para> sometexthere<anchor> xyxyy</anchor></para>`

Expected code

`<para><anchor> xyxyy</anchor> sometexthere </para>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make a couple of changes, and it should work:

First, change

```
anchortag.set()
```

to

```
anchortag.text='xyxy'
```

and then, given that you want `sometexthere` to be at the tail end of the element,

change

```
para1.text= " sometexthere"
```

to

```
para1.tail= "sometexthere"
```